# valueerror: _isdir: embedded null character in path

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, filepath

I am currently working in Spyder 3 (Python 3.7) on my home PC, but just a couple of hours ago Spyder crashed. I don't know what coused the crash, but I received this error message in my anaconda promt when trying to start Spyder from there:

> "valueerror: _isdir: embedded null character in path"

There is also an error message pop-up window that says "Spyder crashed during last session", and tells me to try to use the command `spyder--reset`, but this does not work.

Has anyone here encountered the same problem and knows what to do? Or should I just try to reinstall the software and hope it works? In the case that I reinstall, what files and packages will I lose?

Comment: "embedded null character in path" - it would be interesting to know *which* path exactly it is referring to.

Comment: And what did you change since the last time you were able to do the same thing without that error message?

Comment: The message does not mention which path. When Spyder crashed I was editing some code for a perceptron network, but I cant see why that would interfer with anything. The code does however read a file, can it be something with that maybe?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The command is `spyder --reset`, not `spyder--reset`.

Comment: That did actually help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`spyder --reset` did not work for me.

I manually deleted the folders like ".spyder", ".spyder_bak" etc in my user folder, and finally it worked.